# Getting data from one paragraph and pasting to another using js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get `innerHtml` from one paragraph (`.img-text class`) using JavaScript and then inserting it in another (`.caption class`) when clicked on an image.

My HTML looks like that:

```
        <div class="galle">
          <div class="modal-img">
             <img class="full-img" src="#" alt="pop">
                  <p class="caption"></p>
          </div>
        <div class="card aluminiumCard">
           <img id="imggene" src="img1.png" class="card-img-top alhigh" >
        <div class="card-body imgal">
          <p class="card-text">Genesis 75</p>
          <p class="img-text">Text genesis</p>
        </div>
       </div>
      <div class="card aluminiumCard">
        <img src="img2.png"  class="card-img-top alhigh" alt="..." >
        <div class="card-body imgal">
          <p class="card-text">Imperial</p>
          <p class="img-text">Text imperial</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The Javascript code looks like that:

```
  const modalimg = document.querySelector(".modal-img");
  const previews = document.querySelectorAll(".galle img");
  const original = document.querySelector(".full-img");

  previews.forEach(preview => {
    preview.addEventListener('click', () =>{
      modalimg.classList.add("open");
      original.classList.add("open");

      const originalSrc = preview.getAttribute('src');
      original.src = originalSrc;
  })
 })
```

It's responsible for an image pop up when clicking on an image inside a card. How I can get `innerHTML` data from the `.img-text` class, that's corresponding to the image that has been clicked inside a card and then paste that to the paragraph with `.caption` class?

I have tried:

```
const caption = document.querySelector(".caption");
const text-img = document.querySelectorAll(".img-text");
```

then:

```
const text = text-img.innerHTML
caption.innerHTML = text
```

But it takes data only from the first card.

```js
const modalimg = document.querySelector(".modal-img");
const previews = document.querySelectorAll(".galle img");
const original = document.querySelector(".full-img");

previews.forEach(preview => {
  preview.addEventListener('click', () => {
    modalimg.classList.add("open");
    original.classList.add("open");

    const originalSrc = preview.getAttribute('src');
    original.src = originalSrc;
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="galle">
  <div class="modal-img">
    <img class="full-img" src="#" alt="pop">
    <p class="caption"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card aluminiumCard">
    <img id="imggene" src="img1.png" class="card-img-top alhigh">
    <div class="card-body imgal">
      <p class="card-text">Genesis 75</p>
      <p class="img-text">Text genesis</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card aluminiumCard">
    <img src="img2.png" class="card-img-top alhigh" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body imgal">
      <p class="card-text">Imperial</p>
      <p class="img-text">Text imperial</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried about it so far

Comment: @natre214 I have edited the post.

Comment: I made a snippet of the partial code you have - but the HTML is invalid and missing some things

Answer (score 0):

```js
const image = document.getElementsByClassName("card-img-top");
const renderToCaption = (i) => {
  document.getElementsByClassName("caption")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("img-text")[i].innerHTML;
  document.getElementsByClassName("full-img")[0].setAttribute("src", document.getElementsByClassName("card-img-top")[i].getAttribute("src"));
};
for (let i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
  image[i].addEventListener("click", ()=>renderToCaption(i));
 }
```

```css
.card-img-top, .full-img{
            width: 150px;
            cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="galle">
        <div class="modal-img">
            <img class="full-img" src="#" alt="pop">
            <p class="caption">abc</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card aluminiumCard">
            <img id="imggene" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Android_robot_head.svg/1200px-Android_robot_head.svg.png" class="card-img-top alhigh">
            <div class="card-body imgal">
                <p class="card-text">Genesis 75</p>
                <p class="img-text">Text genesis</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card aluminiumCard">
            <img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/images/HeroHomepage_2880x1200.max-1300x1300.jpg" class="card-img-top alhigh" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body imgal">
                <p class="card-text">Imperial</p>
                <p class="img-text">Text imperial</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Check the code above, i guess this fulfils your need. Don't just copy paste, read and understand how it works.

ADVISE: Consider using vanilla JS instead of jQuery on places where possible.

BEST OF LUCK